# Работа с файлами в си

Tags: c, файлы

Здравствуйте. Обрисую задачу: есть 2 файла input.txt и output.txt
Необходимо в первом файле ввести несколько строк с числами (в каждой строке только 2 числа разделенные пробелом) а во втором вывести то же самое что и в первом. Вот код для работы с первым файлом:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int a, b;
FILE *fp;

char name[] = "input.txt";
char name2[] = "output.txt";
if ((fp = fopen("input", "r")) != NULL) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &a, &b)
}else
{
    printf("no fail");
}fclose(fp);
    exit(1);
```

Как используя функцию fprintf вывести те же строки во второй файл? Несколько строк кода в качестве примера будет весьма неплохо))) Заранее спасибо

Comment: А в чем проблема? еще один fopen для второго файла и fprintf в него.. И кстати, Ваше "no fail" в переводе означает примерно "все ок, нет сбоев" ;-) - как-то не очень гуманно по отношению к пользователю такое выводить в случае ошибки открытия файла :-)

Comment: Почитать описание функции `fprintf()`?

Comment: Вот новый код, но в output ничего не выводится
 int a, b;
 FILE *fp;
 char name[] = "input.txt";
 char name2[] = "output.txt";
 if ((fp = fopen("input", "r")) != NULL) {
  fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &a, &b);

  printf("yes.\n");
 }else
 {
  printf("no");
 }fclose(fp);
  exit(1);
  FILE *fp2 = fopen("output", "r");
  fprintf(fp2, "%d %d\n", a, b); fclose(fp2);

Comment: FILE *fp2 = fopen("output", "w"); - на запись же. и еще... конечно это должно быть ДО exit(1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a, b;
FILE *fp, *op;

char name[] = "input.txt";
char name2[] = "output.txt";
if (((fp = fopen(name, "r")) != NULL) && ((op = fopen(name2, "w")) != NULL))
{
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &a, &b) == 2)
    {
        fprintf(op,"%d %d\n",a,b);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(op);
}
```